# Create an array from a CSV list

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a list in `orders.csv` like so:

```
Order
1025405008
1054003899
1055003868
1079004365
```

I wish to add the unit number (2nd-4th chars) and the entire order number into an array, so it will be like:

```
"0254","1025405008"
"0540","1054003899"
etc
etc
```

I wish to ignore the prefix "1". So far, with my limited PS knowledge, I have created the variables:

```
$Orders = Import-csv c:\Orderlist.csv 
$Units = $Orders | Select @{LABEL="Unit";EXPRESSION={$_.Order.Substring(1,4)}}
```

So I wish to combine the two into an array. I have tried

```
$array = $Units,Orders
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In case of a big CSV file that has just this one column using regexp is much faster than `Select`:

```
$combined = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\Orderlist.csv') `
    -replace '(?m)^\d(\d{4})\d+', '"$1","$&"' `
    -replace '^Order', 'Unit, Order' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

~6x faster on 100k records in a 2MB file (700ms vs 4100ms)

Comment: What does `$&` stand for in the replacement? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Part of the original string that matches the entire pattern.

Comment: Wow, how did I missed that? I always used nested capture groups to achieve this. Nice one!

Comment: [.NET regexp syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#substitutions).

Answer (score 3):

You can just select the Order within your `Select` statement and use the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet to get the desired output:

```
$Orders = Import-csv c:\Orderlist.csv
$unitOrderArray = $Orders | Select @{LABEL="Unit";EXPRESSION={$_.Order.Substring(1,4)}}, Order
$unitOrderArray | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output:**

```
"Unit","Order"
"0254","1025405008"
"0540","1054003899"
"0550","1055003868"
"0790","1079004365"
```

Comment: Hah! That easy (when you know how!). Thanks